# iOS App for Shopify store

Tags: ios, payment-gateway, shopify

I'm creating a custom designed iOS App from scratch for my Shopify store but the thing is I couldn't fetch the order details from the store and connect the shopify payment gateway externally to the iOS app.

I have fully developed the functionality but couldn't find a way to process the payments using Shopify API.

Can anyone help me this please.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do payments yourself. Shopify POS is available for merchants that want mobile payments. Shopify controls payments themselves, hence the hosted platform moniker.